# Extract entries of table of content and the page numbers they link to

Tags: java, python, pdf, itext, pypdf

I have [a PDF file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/t.pdf), which contains a table of content, where each entry links to a page in the file.

How shall I program in Python or Java (or some other languages) to extract the table of content in the following form:

```
entry1  PageNumberEntry1LinkedTo
entry2  PageNumberEntry2LinkedTo
...
```

e.g.

```
Section 2.6. Argument Arrays  2
Section 2.7. Thread-Safe Functions  2
```

(If they can be extracted in some tree data structure according to the structure of table of content, that would be even better, but this can be skipped if not possible.)

I would like to get some help about what Python or Java modules and functions can be used to accomplish that? Such as PDFMiner or pypdf2 in Python, iText in IPython or Java, ...?

Answer (score 1):

I have examined your file and it looks very strange.

See the following screenshot:

[image]

I used [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups) to take a look at the root of the page tree. You probably know that a page in PDF isn't aware of its page number. The page number of a page is determined by the position of the page in the page tree.

In the screen shot, you see part of the page dictionary (object 3) of Page 1 (it's page 1 because `3 0 R` is the first element in the `/Kids` array).

I have opened the array with the annotations, and I see a link annotation with a `/GoTo` action. This action tells a PDF viewer to jump to the page of which the page dictionary is object number 58.

When we examine the page tree (which is actually nothing more than a single branch without any leaves), we see that `58 0 R` refers to page 2 (the second item in the page tree).

However, this can't be right, can it? Page 2 just contains another part of the TOC, so I don't think the links are correct.

It looks as if you created your PDF based on a web page, because I see a `/PA` entry that refers to an HTML page.

**Long story short:**

You need to loop over all the annotations in each page and look for `/Link` annotations. You then have to examine the value of the action (`/A`). This will give you the object ID of the page you're looking for.

As for the text: obviously, the text is not stored in the annotation. For the link shown in the screen shot, you'll have to search for the text inside the rectangle `[107.2 754.3 235.6 763.6]`. That's not impossible, but it's not always trivial.

Your question is a project that requires a couple of days of work. If you want a working example, take into account that you're asking people to contribute more than just a couple of hours of their time.

Comment: Thanks. I modified which pages are linked to, because I am afraid of uploading the whole file. I hope to but have no idea of how to start with iText, I thought it would be a simple program to extract the table of content entries and the pages they linked to. If it takes a lot to program for that, then knowing which classes and functions (and maybe a skeleton program) I need to learn to accomplish that would suffice.

Comment: Content is stored in content streams. Links are stored in annotations. There is no direct link between the content and the link. The only correspondence is that the clickable area (the link) and the text appear at the same position. If you want to know where to start, download [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) and use Ctrl+F for answers that contain `ANNOTS`, `Link`, `extract`,...

Comment: Thanks. By the way, the original pdf file was created from chm file by someone else. The conversion program used didn't extract the bookmarks from the chm to the pdf file. That was where my post came from. Do you know which programs  can do that, or if programming in iText can do that?

Comment: Can I rephrase your question? *You have chm files and you are looking for a tool to convert those to PDF in a way so that the links are preserved.* If that is the question, then the answer is: iText can't do this and I don't know of any other tool that can do this.

Comment: Better not. That is a different question. My post is about parsing an existing pdf file

Comment: In that case, I misunderstood the question. I don't know any tool that can achieve what you want to do. You can of course always write such a tool yourself using iText. You know that content and annotations are separate things. The book explains how to find the annotations and their position on the page. It also explains how to find the text on the page once you have the position. It's only work.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably find some time to study iText. In software such as Adobe Pro, each text entry and its annotation (including link) are associated together, and can be edited together in a dialog after right clicking the text. Not sure how the software was programmed to do that. But it is tedious to manually extract the linked page number for each entry.